# Add www to URL, but ignore m. subdomain

Tags: mod-rewrite, web

I've got my rewrite rule below and it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, it will redirect `m.website.com` to `www.website.com`.
Is there a way I can get it to ignore the m. subdomain? I don't want to have the mobile site be `www.website.com/mobile`

Comment: I don't see how it could redirect `m.website.com` to anywhere in the first place; that does not match `%{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [NC]`.  Something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the subdomain using another RewriteCond.

Rewrite all subdomains except 'm':

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.website.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am not sure how this would be any different that what OP posted, since `HTTP_HOST` will always match the second criteria if it matches the first (it cannot begin with m.website.com if it begins with website.com). Seems there must be something wrong as [@PointedEars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074732/add-www-to-url-but-ignore-m-subdomain#comment-9895114) noted.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the first regex should not include anything else since the beginning of the string is being denoted with `^` but for whatever reason he said it was matching so I informed him of the fact that you can use multiple RewriteCond's in groups.